# Add product information like name, price and url to ("data" Object in) add-to-cart ajax function - Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, object-manager, ajaxaddtocart

I am trying to get some more product data in the add-to-cart event (using ajax). So far, I can see the form works like this:

```
$(document).on('ajax:addToCart', function (event, data) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(data);
});
```

I can see that there is some information in the "data" object already:

```
Object { sku: 8215, productIds: (1) […], form: {…}, response: [] }
form: Object { 0: form, context: form
, length: 1, … }
productIds: Array [ "15" ]
response: Array []
sku: 8215
```

The sku f.e. is now accessible in a script like this:

```
var sku = data.sku;
```

But I also need to know the **price**, the **name** and if possible the **URL** of the product I just added to the cart. How can I add this information to the add-to-cart functionality so it contains this kind of information?

Something like

```
<?php $product->getName() ?>
```

but how does it work via php object?

Answer (score 0):

It's just basic javascript you can extend any object; so

```
let price = "XXX";
data.price = price;
```

If your question is more about how to get the value of price name and url of the product, then you just have to get them from the php object.

Doing something like

```
let name = "<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>";
```

Comment: The question is indeed how to get the values (via php object) since I have no clue where to check for $product. On a product page, I know where to get it. But the add-to-cart function can be on a number of pages with different products. So somehow, the whole add-to-cart ajax setup has to be enhanced.